# Set value to label with a text field

Tags: xcode

I want to make an app that allows the user to enter a value in a text field and from that, it should change the value of a label. I'm new in programming so I don't really know how to code it. In the .m file how should I connect the text field's value to the value of the label?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your textField to this method

```
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField*) txtField
{

[labelField setText: [textField text]]
return YES:
}
```